# How to pass multiple argument to multiple columns in sqlite3?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, parameter-passing

I just want to pass multiple variables to multiple columns to update it, but I'm not sure if my syntax are correct and I don't know how to pass the arguments on both SET and WHERE commands.

```
query = 'UPDATE locker SET title = ?, category = ?, name = ?, link = ?, username = ?, password = ?, note= ? WHERE title = ? AND account_id = ?'
cur.execute(query, ??)
```

Comment: Please always use relevant tags only (your question has nothing to do with PyQt, the fact that you're using it on your program is irrelevant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine to me

```
cur.execute(query, (par1, par2, .., parN))
```